# Magento : Got Protected Data Of Customer in Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer

I tried to get the information about a logged customer into an observer, but I can't get it even when I get customer object and maybe it's because I have the "protected" data

In the Observer file:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); // works
DEBUG (7): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => customer
    [_eventObject:protected] => customer
    [_errors:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [...]
    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
            [entity_id] => 2

--------------------------------------------
$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getData();
// Call to a member function getData() on null
```

How can I get the customer data?

UPDATE

I don't know if it's a good way to do it, but it works better:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

Comment: Can you specify which information of customer you want into observer?

Comment: With the customerId could be enought

Answer (score 0):

To get customer Id, you need to used this code.

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$customer_Id = $customer->getId();
```

Or

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$customer_Id = $customer->getEntityId();
```

Comment: But if I didn't use the `if` it didn't works, it's like the code should wait a moment to load the customer

Comment: Which event observer you are specify? Do you mean, you do not put if condition then you didn't get infromation?

Comment: I don't think the event is important. The responses are:
`$customer->getData(); // error, $customer is null, but if I did:
if($customer){$customer->getData();} // works`